# How to show result of rake task in view file in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to create a parser based on Rails App and I use for this 'nokogiri'. I watched railscast by Ryan Bates about this but I don't understand how he integrated task with view.

For example: In my view file I press the button - task starts to collect information and shows this information on the same page. How can I do this?

My example task:

```
desc "example"
task :parsing => :environment do
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'

  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML'))
  page.css('div#content div#bodyContent table.infobox tr th').each do |el|
    puts el.text
  end
end
```

Or maybe I shouldn't use for parser rake task? Maybe I should put my parser in controller or in model or in helper?

Comment: Rake tasks are intended for administrative work, not for background jobs to be triggered by application users.

Comment: Recently I changed Nokogiri to Mechanize and now I want to know how to put my sorted information into mysql2 database. So, how can I achieve my goal? What should I do?

Comment: What you can do is ask a separate question here, with specifics on what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried, and what the desired result is.